# ZXingScannerView in the ZXing.Net.Mobile library

Tags: barcode

I'm trying to have a custom view in ZXingScannerView of my Xamarin project. The goal is to have to a Target Area (A red Square) so that the end user can focus on the QR Code and a cancel button within the ZXingScannerView, to end the scanning activity.

Any ideas?